# Int32 for ASP.NET Core claim value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

It looks like claims are way to go with ASP.NET Core (3.1) authorization, but my question is how can we have integer values not only strings? I want to store some IDs in the claims:

```
var userid = 123;  // try "123"
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userid, ClaimValueTypes.Integer32));
```

Or any better way to do it? 
TIA

Answer (score 3):

The claims can only be represented as strings. So you can convert userid to string , and on other side decode token , get claim and convert to int again if needed .